# MariaDB install OQGRAPH as DB Engine in AWS RDS

Tags: sql, mariadb, amazon-rds, oqgraph

Is it possible to install OQGRAPH on a AWS RDS instance? If yes how?

Reading the installation guide: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-oqgraph/ installing OQGRAPH requires admin-access to the server - which clearly RDS does not grant.

Any ideas on how to install it anyways?

Obviously if i just run

```
INSTALL SONAME 'ha_oqgraph';
```

I do get the following Error-Message:

> Can't open shared library
>   '/rdsdbbin/mariadb-10.0.24.R1/lib/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so' (errno: 2,
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Comment: Ask Amazon :-(
https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/
And post the answer back :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately it is currently not available.

According to the [AWS RDS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MariaDB.Options.html) the only plugin currently available for the RDS MariaDB is the Audit Plugin, which was [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/mariadb-audit-plug-in-now-available-for-rds-mysql-and-mariadb/) only few months back.

If you still want to use MariaDB on AWS, but you are not forced to use RDS - you can have your own Instance of MariaDB (using the available Community MariaDB AMIs, or one of the [AMIs provided by MariaDB](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?ref=cns_srchrow&id=86b7bfa0-af85-4bfa-b735-e719e6fce277), which available for CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu). This way you have full access to your server, so you will not have any problem with installing new plugins.